# Limit Multiple id Only 2 Rows to Show in MySQL

Tags: mysql, limit

How to show all data but limit the same id value only 2 rows to show
for example, here is my table 'test':

```
id  name    created_at
1   a       2019-01-02
1   b       2019-01-03
1   c       2019-01-04
1   d       2019-01-05
1   e       2019-01-06
2   f       2019-01-07
2   g       2019-01-08
2   h       2019-01-09
3   i       2019-01-10
3   j       2019-01-11
3   k       2019-01-12
4   l       2019-01-13
```

and i want the output to get all data, but limit only 2 rows to show if it's same id, like this:

```
id  name    created_at
1   d       2019-01-05
1   e       2019-01-06
2   g       2019-01-08
2   h       2019-01-09
3   j       2019-01-11
3   k       2019-01-12
4   l       2019-01-13
```

Comment: which two rows? What MySQL version?

Comment: Limit the same id value only 2 rows to show. Mine version 5.6

Comment: Why do you want 'a' and 'b' for id 1 as opposed to 'd' and 'e'?

Comment: I want to be able to get the the oldest or the latest data

Comment: How do you know which is the oldest or latest data?

Comment: I'm sorry in my table there is created at column. let me edit that

Comment: I've edited that

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH Top2 AS (
    SELECT
        Id,
        Name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id) AS RowCount
    FROM Test
)
SELECT
    Id,
    Name
FROM Top2
WHERE RowCount <= 2
```

Updated with another solution, I’ve not tested it yet

```
SET @RowCount = 0;
SET @LId = 0;

SELECT
    T.Id,
    T.Name
FROM (
    SELECT
          @RowCount := CASE WHEN @LId = Id THEN @RowCount + 1 ELSE 1 END AS RowCount,
          @LId := Id AS Id ,
          Name
    FROM Test
    ORDER BY Id
    ) T
WHERE T.RowCount <= 2;
```

Comment: it said Unrecognized statement type. (near "WITH" at position 0)

Comment: I don't think that ROW_NUMBER() OVER bit is going to work on MySql 5.6 (the version in the question).

Comment: Oops, I tested on the latest version of MySql

Comment: Well, if OP upgrade to version 8.0, this would be the solution

Comment: I updated my answer with another solution but I don’t have 5.6 on my machine so still don’t know if it works or not:P

Comment: OP has posted 3 similar question since yesterday :/